# Some added products in cross sells not visible in frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection, cross-sells, visibility

I have added few products in cross-sells but some are visible and some are not visible in the UI(frontend).

I referred to a Magento bug that only 2 items were visible in the backend

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13720

Is this related to Magento 2 bug, How can I solve this bug.

> ***`Catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php`***

```
 class CollectionProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionProviderInterface[]
     */
    protected $providers;

    /**
     * @var ConverterPool
     */
    protected $converterPool;

    /**
     * @param ConverterPool $converterPool
     * @param CollectionProviderInterface[] $providers
     */
    public function __construct(ConverterPool $converterPool, array $providers = [])
    {
        $this->converterPool = $converterPool;
        $this->providers = $providers;
    }

    /**
     * Get product collection by link type
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @param string $type
     * @return array
     * @throws NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $type)
    {
        if (!isset($this->providers[$type])) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The collection provider isn't registered."));
        }

        $products = $this->providers[$type]->getLinkedProducts($product);
        $converter = $this->converterPool->getConverter($type);
        $sorterItems = [];
        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getId();
            $sorterItems[$itemId] = $converter->convert($item);
            $sorterItems[$itemId]['position'] = $sorterItems[$itemId]['position'] ?? 0;

        }

        usort($sorterItems, function ($itemA, $itemB) {
            $posA = intval($itemA['position']);
            $posB = intval($itemB['position']);
            return $posA <=> $posB;
        });

        return $sorterItems;

    }

}
```

This was the fix for only a few products showing in the backend(admin panel).

How can I fix the same issue for frontend? All cross-sell products are visible in the backend now but not visible in the frontend(UI).

Comment: If you are working with configurable products, check if their Stock Status attribute are up to date and also the simple products.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify with below points :

> check stock options - check your stock availability is 'In stock' or not...
>
> clear cache
>
> reindex data -
>
> check xml files - may be something wrong with your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure

> All Product Visible (visibility set to Catalog and Search )
>
> All Products Status Enable and In stock

and if above is OK then run index command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```